# Dual screen in Windows 7 not working

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi

I cloned an image of my desktop to another desktop with the same hardware.
I'm connecting 2 DELL Monitors with DVI-I Dual Link, both of them working on POST,CMOS Setup and Windows Loading, but not on windows.


OS: Windows 7

Display Card : ATI Radeon HD 3400 Series

Any suggestions?

Tried so far

- re install drivers
- download updater from amd
- unplug / plug display card
- change the position of DVI cables at DVI-I adapter (again one monitor working)
- replace all the cables with news
- test all cables and monitors to another desktop
- tested 4 same monitors
- screen resolution -> detect (nothing)
- windows key+ break -> device manager -> monitors  (only one)

Comment: Even if you cloned the image you may still have to repeat the driver setup to clone/extend your desktop.

Comment: i have re installed the drivers 3-4 times

Comment: That's not what I said.  You have to go into the settings and extend/clone your desktop.  Your new monitors will have a ID's and windows will only automatically display to one of them.

Comment: i didn't said that i have tried that because it is so obvious!